# Sqlite db won't connect

Tags: python, database, sqlite, oop

I am trying to implement a function that adds a habit to a habit tracker app that I am building. I have created a separate database.py file and a main.py file for the interface. There is a problem connecting to my database.py file from the code below:

```
self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.duration = duration
        self.database = establish_connection('main.db')
        self.streak = 0
        self.start_time = date.today().strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
        
    def add_habit(self):
        if habit_exists(self.database, self.name) is False:
            self.database.add(self.database, self.name, self.description, self.duration, self.start_time, self.streak)
            print(f'{self.name} has been added to the database as a {self.duration} habit starting on {self.start_time}\n')
            
        else: 
            print(f'{self.name} already exists in the database\n')
```

My database file has a function for adding the habit info into my database by using the following:

```
def add(db, name, description, duration, start_time, streak):
    """Adds a habit to the database

    Args:
        db (sqlite3.connect): _description_
        name (str): _description_
        description (str): _description_
        duration (str): _description_
        start_time (str): _description_
        streak (int): _description_
    """
    db = establish_connection('main.db')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO habits (name, description, duration, start_time, streak) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)''', (name, description, duration, start_time, streak))
    db.commit()
```

When I run my main.py file, I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/brandon/IU International University/Object-Oriented and Functional Programing with Python/Habit Tracker/main.py", line 89, in 
interface()

File "/home/brandon/IU International University/Object-Oriented and Functional Programing with Python/Habit Tracker/main.py", line 40, in interface
habit.add_habit()

File "/home/brandon/IU International University/Object-Oriented and Functional Programing with Python/Habit Tracker/habit.py", line 39, in add_habit
self.database.add(self.database, self.name, self.description, self.duration, self.start_time, self.streak)

AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Connection' object has no attribute 'add'

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `self.database` is not your `database.py` file, it is whatever `establish_connection('main.db')` returns. Based on the error message, that appears to be an `sqlite3.Connection` object. Do you mean to call `database.add()` instead of `self.database.add()`?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous description. The database.py and main.py simply contain the functions that I displayed originally. What I am trying to achieve is establishing that sqlite connection and then using the second function to add the chosen habit into it.